# ValueError: y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape (295, 9) instead

Tags: python, machine-learning, sentiment-analysis, tf-idf, naivebayes

I have a sentiment dataset about opinions on Twitter after I process them and I label these sentiments and I want to share the data based on the sentiments I labeled. now when I share it using the model `train_test_split` code it works when I match it to the predict stage model using naive bayes there is an error value `ValueError: y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape (295, 9) instead.` whether the distribution is not right or what?

[spreadsheet dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WrDTTvevtOrbuQZFzfB1PNX7KDVp4V72/view?usp=share_link)

#### #Train Test Split

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test  = train_test_split(text_tf, sentimen, test_size=0.78, random_state=0)
```

### **#Naive Bayes**

```
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, precision_score, recall_score, f1_score
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
clf = MultinomialNB()
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
predicted = clf.predict(X_test)

print("MultinomialNB Accuracy:", accuracy_score(y_test,predicted))
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-55-90624fc1891c> in <module>
      4 from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
      5 clf = MultinomialNB()
----> 6 clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
      7 predicted = clf.predict(X_test)
      8 

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in column_or_1d(y, warn)
   1037 
   1038     raise ValueError(
-> 1039         "y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape {} instead.".format(shape)
   1040     )
   1041 

ValueError: y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape (295, 9) instead.
```

i have tried to change the `test_size` and `random_state` part but it only change on value error says same thing only change on size instead

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB.html

> fit(X, y, sample_weight=None) Fit Naive Bayes classifier according to
> X, y.

> yarray-like of shape (n_samples,)  Target values.

y should be a one-dimensional array